# Celery can't get result from given task

Tags: python, celery

I try to configure celery with rabbitmq. Server works fine, my worker receive task and return succeded result but communication(?) fail. I'm following first steps from celery doc. I started tasks worker and created file tasks.py. My connection:

```
app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://')
```

Logs inside worker (correct):

```
[2015-03-13 21:00:46,146: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.add[ee0fd026-d08e-4380-b010-9bbe65cb8b8f] succeeded in 0.00891784499981s: 4
```

but can't get result and the status is pending

```
add_task = tasks.add.delay(2,2)

In [4]: add_task.status
Out[4]: 'PENDING'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_task.status` gets the state of the task as soon as you queue it (remember, you are using `.delay`, not executing it immediately), which will be `PENDING`.

To get the state of the task from the backend use `AsyncResult`.

```
res = tasks.add.AsyncResult(add_task.task_id)
```

This will work, unless you have set the backend to ignore task results.

Comment: No problem. Mark the answer if it solved your query.